# Windows Phone 7 Emulator Location Data Format

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am looking for a format of the location data used by the Windowws Phone Emulator Additional Tools. On the tab "Location" there is an option to save/open recorder data. I ask this question because I need simulate geo position change but Location Tab doesn't work for me. As a workaround I am going to create a file of the location data and open it in the emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a simple XML file in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<WindowsPhoneEmulator xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WindowsPhoneEmulator/2009/08/SensorData"> 
    <SensorData> 
        <Header version="1" /> 
        <GpsData latitude="" longitude="" /> 
        <GpsData latitude="" longitude="" /> 
        <GpsData latitude="" longitude="" /> 
    </SensorData> 
</WindowsPhoneEmulator>
```

Answered thanks to "Konaju Games" user at AppHub forum (http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/91880/550593.aspx)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it's the answer you were looking for. ;) @CaptainO.