# wp7 emulator map screen is white

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation, bing-maps

I recently reinstalled Windows 8 CP, Visual Studio 2010 Professional and both the WP7 SDKs. My emulator map is just a white screen - the interface is present but there's no map.

I have an internet connection and I've reinstalled both SDKs.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the emulator location tool is not working for some reason. It has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710237/windows-phone-7-emulator-location-data-format), and I gave a suggestion on what to do both [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710237/windows-phone-7-emulator-location-data-format) and on my [blog](http://igrali.com/2012/07/30/windows-phone-location-tool-in-emulator-down-no-problem/).

I hope this will get you going! :-)